# docker-compose - Can I update traefik labels without restarting a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Can I update labels on a container using docker-compose without restarting the container?

Ideal scenario:
  - change labels in docker-compose.yml
  - save docker-compose.yml
  - run a command to update the labels without restarting the container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, changing the settings or code running inside a container involves deleting and restarting the container.  This is totally normal, and `docker-compose up` will do it for you when necessary.  (Remember to make sure any data you care about is stored outside the container.)

At a Docker API level, there are only a limited set of things that can be changed in the [Update a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerUpdate) call, and labels aren’t one of those.  That means anything that manages a container, whether direct `docker` commands or Docker Compose, must always delete and recreate a container to change its labels.

Comment: Got it! I wasn't aware of it. I found the following links confirming this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15496 and https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/18958. I wish it would be possible to tweak minor changes in traefik-labels without bringing down a container but it's apparently not possible.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you can work around it by using the [File provider](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/) as a way to tweak configuration without restarting your services.