# Remove Docker service labels without restarting the containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We are using Docker Swarm. We deployed the service with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml Application`. During the lifetime of a service, we want to remove one of service labels (`service-custom-label`) with `docker service update --label-rm service-custom-label Application_web`. We noticed that after running this command, website is unavailable for ~10 seconds because containers are restarted in the background.

Is it possible to remove Docker service labels without restarting containers in the background and thus not causing website downtime?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062007/docker-compose-can-i-update-labels-without-restarting-a-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose - Can I update labels without restarting a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062007/docker-compose-can-i-update-labels-without-restarting-a-container)

Comment: As far as I know, labels defined in the `deploy` section of `docker-compose.yml` file aren't stored in container but in Docker service. So, I don't want to change container labels, I want to change **Docker service** labels.

Comment: its almost like you answered your own question. But if the website is going down, perhaps run more than one replica.